# Why does different factorisation matter in Markov networks?

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, hidden-markov-model, graphical-model

I have been reading about Markov Networks that given some set of factors we can construct a unique graph G but not the other way around:
"It should also be noticed that, given a set of factors, the Markov network is unique; given a Markov network, we cannot read factorization from the network."

While I understand how this is the case, why is it important? If I have a factor over a,b and c(F(a,b,c)) instead of 3 factors of every combination(F(a,b),F(b,c),F(a,c)), don't they express the same thing? And cant I get the individual factors by marginalization over F(a,b,c)?

Answer (score 1):

It matters a lot in practice. First, having factors with several variables means, that you need samples in your database where these come up together.

Think for example of natural language processing. If each variable represents a possible word, you see that in order to train it, you would need texts where all tuples of possible words appears. Which leads to very sparse data (only a small fraction of words tend to show up together).

So the smaller the factor, the better. But also factorization encodes some previous knowledge/asumptions about how the data was generated. So in addition to requiring less data, training is less computationally expensive (there are many algorithms which exploit the graph structure to save many computations like variable elimination and tree decompositions of the graph) and the model achieves much better accuracy. Again, the key is that your model fits the application you are targeting.